# Binomial vs Probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, combinations

> A shipment of 12 microwave ovens contains 3 defective units. A vending company has ordered 4 of these units, and because all are packaged identically, the selection will be at random. What is the probability that at least 2 units are good?

There are two ways to solve this problem:

1. Using the binomial distribution: 
   \begin{align*}
   P(\text{defective}) & = \frac{3}{12} = \frac{1}{4}\\
   P(\text{good}) & = 1 - \frac{1}{4} = \frac{3}{4}\\
   P(2~\text {good}) & = \binom{4}{2} \times 0.75^{2} \times 0.25^{2} = 0.211\\
   P(3~\text{good}) & = \binom{4}{3}\times 0.75^{3} \times 0.25 = 0.422\\
   P(4~\text{good}) & = 0.75^{4} = 0.316
   \end{align*}
   The probability that at least 2 units are good is given by:
   $$P(2~\text{good}) + P(3~\text{good}) + P(4~\text{good}) = 0.211 + 0.422 + 0.316 = 0.949$$
2. Using combinations:
   $$\frac{\dbinom{9}{2}\dbinom{3}{2} + \dbinom{9}{3}\dbinom{3}{1} + \dbinom{9}{4}}{\dbinom{12}{4}} = \frac{486}{495} = \frac{54}{55} = 0.9818$$

Why are these two answers different?

Comment: Please use MathJax for mathematical equations and expressions: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use the binomial distribution, as this is an experiment without replacement: once you pick a defective oven, there are only two defective ovens left. Using combinations, the probability of selecting at least two good units indeed equals:

$$\frac{{9 \choose 4}{3 \choose 0} + {9 \choose 3}{3 \choose 1} + {9 \choose 2}{3 \choose 2}}{12 \choose 4} \approx 0.982$$

Comment: You should say defective oven.  Defect is a noun.  Defective is an adjective.  The mathematics is flawless.

Comment: @N. F. Taussig Corrected!